# How to make the 'dashboard' view returns if the user is logged in, else 'welcome' view return on Laravel?

Tags: routes, laravel-blade, laravel-9, laravel-jetstream

I will give an example from Stack Overflow;

The page that returns when the user is not logged in:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00Qb6.png)

The page that returns when the user is logged in: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1HG3.png)

Different views are shown on the same route ('/'). I wanna do exactly this.

I am using Laravel Jetstream.

I couldn't figure out whether I should do it from routes/web.php, User Controller or Jetstream Controllers.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LoginController;


Route::middleware('admin:admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('admin/login', [LoginController::class, 'loginForm']);
    Route::post('admin/login', [LoginController::class, 'store'])->name('admin.login');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum,admin', config('jetstream.auth_session'), 'verified'
])->group(function () {
    Route::get('admin/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('admin.dashboard')->middleware('auth:admin');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', config('jetstream.auth_session'), 'verified'
])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');
});
```

Comment: Basically, the default Laravel `welcome.blade.php` does this:
`@auth
Do something when you're logged in
@else
Do something when you're NOT logged in
@endauth`

Comment: I want to do it in the same way as Stackoverflow, Instagram, Github did. This way is a bit amateurish. I guess I should use middleware but I couldn't find how.

routes/web.php

`Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', config('jetstream.auth_session'), 'verified'
])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');
});`